# Connecting with a service via PHP cURL to send data not working

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm trying to POST to the linksalpha API. I've tried countless ways but I don't even get a response from their servers when it comes to [post](http://apidocs.linksalpha.com/methods/post).

Here is the [dev page](http://julianjosephs.com/linksalpha.php) that I've setup. The content multipart response looks weird to me. The code I've written (api now hidden) is below. Nothing I try to do works :( :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
$link = 'http://api.linksalpha.com/ext/post';

$data = array(
    'api_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'post_id' => '434345',
    'post_link' => 'www.google.com',
    'post_title' => 'test title',
    'post_content' => 'test msg'
);

function networkpub_http_post($link, $body) {

    $url = $link;
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    function dbg_curl_data($ch, $data=null) {
      static $buffer = '';

      if ( is_null($ch) ) {
        $r = $buffer;
        $buffer = '';
        return $r;
      }
      else {
        $buffer .= $data;
        return strlen($data);
      }
    }

    echo '<fieldset><legend>request headers</legend>
      <pre>', htmlspecialchars(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT)), '</pre>
    </fieldset>';

    echo '<fieldset><legend>response</legend>
      <pre>', htmlspecialchars(dbg_curl_data(null)), '</pre>
    </fieldset>';



    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;

}


    $response_full = networkpub_http_post($link, $data);

    echo($response_full);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `The content multipart response looks weird to me` can you add this response to pastbin for further analysis

Answer (score 1):

if you pass `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS with array` then it will count as `multipart/form-data` but to post data through cURL then you need `application/x-www-form-urlencoded version`

So put following before your function start

```
$body = http_build_query($body);
```

Comment: I did that, the form changed but it still doesn't sent to the service.

Comment: what you get var_dump($response) just after $response = curl_exec($ch); this line ??

Comment: string(0) "" - you can see it on my link as well